# Not Able to load my static files after connecting Gcloud bucket with Django App

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, django-staticfiles

I have a Django App on which i have set the default file storage to my bucket in my google cloud console and also set the other required environment variables in my settings.py like this

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'agevent-xxxx.appspot.com'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID =  'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "agevent-XXXXXXXXX.json"
)
```

And i have also manually uploaded my static folder (inlcluding all files) to my bucket. 
Currently im using these variables in my settings.py for static files

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/agevent-XXXXX.appspot.com/face_detector/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

and in my app.yaml im using these values for static

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: https://storage.googleapis.com/agevent-XXXXXX.appspot.com/face_detector/static/
```

But the problem is when my django app loads on the GAE server, my static files do not load neither the images nor the styling files.

I am quite a rookie in python and gae so please suggest me some basic answers

for all those steps i have done, i followed the following link
https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html#installation

Comment: sorry :) corrected

Comment: FYI, the credentials are still in the edit history. You should rotate your credentials.

Comment: Did you tested how it works on on-premise? Maybe problem is in the app not in the storage setup...

Comment: Are you running collectstatic prior to deploying? I'm not sure, but you may need to specify the GS_PROJECT_ID in your settings.py account as well. In the mean time, you can upload your static files manually using gsutil, run `gsutil -m rsync -r ./static gs://<your-bucket-name>/static` source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/serving-static-files